# How do you resolve ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError for a Ruby only (sinatra) application?

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

How do I enable the creation of new objects that are inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`?

When I run the following lines:

```
params[:book] = {:title => "Catcher in the Rye", :author => "JD Salinger"}
@book = Book.new(params[:book])
```

error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
# ./vendor/bundle/gems/activemodel-4.1.7/lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:21:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
  # ./vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:24:in `assign_attributes'
...
```

models/books.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

gems

```
gem "activerecord"
gem "sinatra"
gem "thin"
gem "pg"
```

Comment: for some reason, I was unable to reproduce your error, but you probably want to read documentation about strong parameters https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Comment: Where did your `params` hash come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably running into ActiveRecord's mass assignment protection.

You can read more about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), but the basics are that passing a list of parameters which come directly from a POST request can open up a class of security errors where an attacker can set values on an object without going through your validation code.

Your code is essentially a "false positive" for that protection, since the only values you're actually passing to `new` are ones you defined directly.

For your code, better to avoid `params` altogether, since you're not actually using any values in it.  I would write that code like this:

```
book_params = {:title => "Catcher in the Rye", :author => "JD Salinger"}
@book = Book.new(book_params)
```

Or, even:

```
@book = Book.new({:title => "Catcher in the Rye", :author => "JD Salinger"})
```